# Prediction method where predictors and response variable are binary

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, cross-validation, binary-data

I have a group of binary tasks performed by multiple subjects. Every task can be either performed right or wrong (i.e.,1/0). My goal is to predict the accuracy of future task given the performance on previous tasks. As tasks considered to be independent, I thought that it makes sense to average the accuracy by making predictions for every task given the rest.

Could you please advise me what is a suitable regression or any predictive model for this kind of data

Additionally, I am interested in cross validation between variables: Lets say I have 10 variables. I'm interested in averaged accuracy of prediction when first 9 variables are predictors and the last one is the response variable, then variables 1-8,10 are predictors and 9th is the response variable, and so on such that every variable calculated once as a response variable.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You provided no context, especially with regard why it is relevant to cascade sets of predictors.  How many regression courses have you taken?

Comment: This appears to be a candidate for alternating logistic regression (ALR).  ALR is not set up to have a variable number of predictors, though.  Predictors need to have the same form for each successive occurrence, and you also need independent replicates (e.g., multiple measurements on _multiple subjects_).  One way that ALR can be set up is to have the following predictors: previous response, 2nd previous response, proportion of past responses that were positive, time zero (baseline) variables.  If you use the 2nd previous response your first observation per subject will 3rd in the sequence.

Comment: It is not clear from your original post whether this is a series of binary responses in _the same_ individuals, and where there are many individuals, or not. Can you edit your post to illuminate what your data look like, and what you study design was?

Comment: I have edited my post. Hope It's clear now.